# GWT How to get checkBox value when click button

Tags: html, gwt

I am new to GWT. Here is my checkBox code, I want to know whether it is chose or not when user click button.

```
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Disable Credential");
    checkBox.setValue(false);
    flexTable3.setWidget(0, 0, checkBox);
    checkBox.getElement().setId("checkBox");
    flexTable3.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 0, 2);
    flexTable3.getFlexCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(0, 0,
            HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Here is my getting checkbox value code in onclick handler class :

```
InputElement checkBoxElement = (InputElement) (Element) DOM
                            .getElementById("checkBox");

if (checkBoxElement.getValue() != null) {

                        checkBox = checkBoxElement.getValue() != null;}
```

Based on my code, the checkBox result is always false no matter it's chose or not. Any idea how to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GWT you almost never need to set an id on an element and get an element by id. You already have your CheckBox widget in your code - use it.

```
checkbox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean> () {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        if (event.getValue()) {
            // check box is selected
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the onValueChange handler?